# placing divs in a circle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code which places divs around a circle.  However, I want to rotate the circle to change the sequence of divs from the top of the circle.

```
function drawCircle(selector, center, radius, angle, x, y)
    {


    var total = $(selector).length;
    var alpha = Math.PI * 2 / total;

    $(selector).each(function(index)
    {
        var theta = alpha * index;
        var pointx = Math.floor(Math.cos( theta ) * radius);
        var pointy = Math.floor(Math.sin( theta ) * radius );


        $(this).css('margin-left', pointx + x + 'px');
        $(this).css('margin-top', pointy + y + 'px');
    });

   }


  $(document).ready(function()
  {


   drawCircle('.box', 0, 250, 0, 500, 500);

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var theta = Math.PI/2 - alpha * index;
```

That was hard :p

Comment: Excellent..so how can I now flip the circle vertical (mirror in x axis)?

Comment: This is what I have now, but the div at the bottom needs to be at the top.  So flipping the circle vertically will  get the sequence of divs right (not rotating by 180 degrees though...) http://jsfiddle.net/xMdaf/

Comment: `Math.PI/3*2 + alpha * index`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  I'll go back to my original question of how I can rotate the circle of divs by entering a number for the angle.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Math.PI/2*3`

Answer (score 0):

Why not rotate everything with CSS? Just use the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) property.