# JS display text tangent to a circle

Tags: javascript, css, text, transform, geometry

Here is what I have so far 
https://jsfiddle.net/0p7zf13x/5/

Here is what I would like to obtain
[Text around circle,  and tangent to its center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRDNg.jpg)

The code is on jsfiddle, but here is a little piece of it.

```
    var count = $("#rollo ul li").length;
var cx = 300;
var cy = 300;
var r = 300;

$("#rollo ul li").each(function(index) {
    var theta = 2 * Math.PI * (index / count);
    var left = cx + r * Math.sin(theta);
    var top = cy - r * Math.cos(theta);
    console.log(index, left, top);
    $(this).css({ left: left, top: top });

        $(this).css({"transform":"rotate("+Math.cos(theta)*-90+"deg)"});
});
```

I started from this code page
[placing divs in a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207689/placing-divs-in-a-circle)

Question : How to make texts around circle and left side of first letter, tangent to that same circle ? All texts evenly distributed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the angle you're generating from:

```
$(this).css({"transform":"rotate("+(theta-Math.PI/2)+"rad)"});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zw3v5xav/)